# How to create a temporary MySQL table with a UUID name in Coldfusion?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, temp-tables

I'm using `Coldfusion8` and `MySQL 5.0.91` and am trying to create a temporary table, import some data from CSV, validate, store in database and drop the temp table.

I can do all steps in MySQL directly, where it works without a problem. However when I try to create the temp table in Coldfusion I keep getting a MySQL error.

This is what I have:

```
<cfset variables.tt = CreateUUID()>
<cfquery datasource="#session.datasource#">
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ##variables.tt;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ##variables.tt (
      tmp_kto VARCHAR(7) DEFAULT ''
    , tmp_kz VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ''
    , tmp_preisliste VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT ''
    , tmp_eg VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ''
    ) ENGINE=MEMORY;
 </cfquery>
```

which does not work. I also tried `#variables.tt#` and plain `variables.tt` but I keep getting the same error, while it works fine when I run the code in MySQL directly (with table name "test")

**Question**:
I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Is there a max length for table names perhaps?

Thanks for some insights.

**EDIT:**
I get the usual error:

```
 you have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #variables.tt (tmp_sa VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ''
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Perhaps ColdFusion does not allow multiple statements?

Comment: what is a multiple statement? I'm getting the usual... see edit above

Comment: @marko - yes would be an option, but a temp table seemed better to me, because I'm not creating and removing tables all the time.

Comment: @frequent By "multiple statements", I was referring to the fact that the submitted code executes two different statements (a `DROP` and a `CREATE`).  It was just a guess.

Comment: Why do you need a temp table then? Can't you do "the stuff" in CF. I'm thinking of Array of Structs.

Comment: Could it be a permisson issue? But wouldn't I get a permission error then?

Comment: @Marko: I could dump everything into an array, but I would need to "query" that array quite a bit and I'm not sure if I'm able to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely source of your problem is that the uuid is not suitable as a tablename.  For one thing, it contains hyphens.  I don't know if MySQL allows this, but I can't remember ever seeing hyphens in a table name.

We have a similar situation, but with redbrick.  We want to create unique names for temporary tables.  Our approach, written in a custom tag, is to use the string "temp" followed by a random number.  We also have some try/catch stuff going on in case we get really unlucky with the random number.

I wrote that tag several years ago.  If I were to do it again, I would probably replace the random number with the cftoken, cfid, and tickcount.

Also, you can't drop a table before you create it.

Comment: seems to have been it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me you are missing the hash marks around your variable to output.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ##variables.tt (
```

should be

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #variables.tt# (
```

The way you have it, MySQL is attempting to use the string `#variables.tt` (the doubled hash escapes the character in ColdFusion) when what you want is to create a temp table with the name of the *value* of variables.tt.

Comment: hm. But the whole thing is working with single hashes, too like `#variables.tt#`. Possible?

Comment: @frequent - Yes. But the syntax for creating temporary tables is database dependent. MS SQL Server uses the prefix `#` for temporary tables and MySQL does not. So it would work in one, but not the other. However, all that matters is the sql string you end up with once the variables are resolved. (That is what is sent to the database). You can easily check it by doing a `cfoutput` of the query (without the tags obviously). Then checking the syntax of the generated sql string.

Comment: agree. so I added the double hashes.

Comment: Re:*I added the double hashes* Why? They are not needed in MySQL. The problem with the original syntax was the *placement* of your pound signs. Assuming no invalid characters, this syntax works just fine: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #variables.tt# (...)` when executed as a single statement.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the syntax difference between MS SQL and MySQL. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Yeah, mySQL uses the `temporary` keyword to indicate temp tables, whereas MS SQL Server (and Sybase too I think) use `#` signs instead.